# Adsense Reports Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, adsense

I am using this code to generate Adsense reports on a Google spreadsheet.

The problem is that it creates a new spreadsheet every day, causing confusion in my reports.

What should I change, so that a single spreadsheet is created, so that the same spreadsheet is updated every day?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/adsense

```js
/**
 * Generates a spreadsheet report for an ad client.
 * @param {string} adClientId The ad client ID
 */
function generateReport(adClientId) {
  // Prepare report.
  var today = new Date();
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  var timezone = Session.getTimeZone();
  var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  var report = AdSense.Reports.generate(startDate, endDate, {
    // Specify the desired ad client using a filter.
    filter: ['AD_CLIENT_ID==' + escapeFilterParameter(adClientId)],
    metric: ['PAGE_VIEWS', 'AD_REQUESTS', 'AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE', 'CLICKS',
             'AD_REQUESTS_CTR', 'COST_PER_CLICK', 'AD_REQUESTS_RPM',
             'EARNINGS'],
    dimension: ['DATE'],
    // Sort by ascending date.
    sort: ['+DATE']
  });

  if (report.rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('AdSense Report');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = report.headers.map(function(header) {
      return header.name;
    });
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
        .setValues(report.rows);

    Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}

/**
 * Escape special characters for a parameter being used in a filter.
 * @param {string} parameter The parameter to be escaped.
 * @return {string} The escaped parameter.
 */
function escapeFilterParameter(parameter) {
  return parameter.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace(',', '\\,');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to use the same Spreadsheet without creating new Spreadsheet.
- In your script, you want to add the data to the new sheet every time.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your case, I think that your goal can be achieved by modifying the script of `###` of `if (report.rows) {###}`.
- For achieving your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the data.
  2. When the Spreadsheet is existing, the data is put to the existing Spreadsheet.

     - In this case, the Spreadsheet ID is saved to PropertiesService.
  3. When the Spreadsheet is not existing, the data is put to the Spreadsheet by creating new Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
if (report.rows) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('AdSense Report');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Append the headers.
  var headers = report.headers.map(function(header) {
    return header.name;
  });
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  // Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
      .setValues(report.rows);

  Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
      spreadsheet.getUrl());
} else {
  Logger.log('No rows returned.');
}
```

To:

```
if (report.rows) {
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var spreadsheetId = prop.getProperty("spreadsheetId");
  var spreadsheet;
  if (spreadsheetId) {
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  } else {
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('AdSense Report');
    prop.setProperty("spreadsheetId", spreadsheet.getId());
  }
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clear();  // Clear sheet.

  // Append the headers.
  var headers = report.headers.map(function(header) {return header.name});
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  // Append the results.
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length).setValues(report.rows);

  Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
} else {
  Logger.log('No rows returned.');
}
```

#### Note:

- In above modified script, the existing Spreadsheet is checked using the Spreadsheet ID saved at PropertiesService. So at first, when you run the script, new Spreadsheet is created and save the Spreadsheet ID. After 2nd run, the data is put to the existing Spreadsheet without creating new Spreadsheet.
- If you want to append the data to the last row of the existing Spreadsheet, please tell me.

#### References:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Neto Oliveira Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But about your new questions, I thought that this is also useful for other users. So can you post it as new question rather than the answer is added to this question? By this, it can be used as a question and when the issue was resolved, it will be useful for you and other users. How about this? If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.